# Passing arguments between procedures

Tags: vba, excel-2016, byref, byval

I have some pretty simple code where I am trying to pass an argument from one sub (call parent) to another; modify some values, not modify some others and finish. i seem to fail miserably. not sure why. Here is some code

```
Sub Parent_sub()
Dim v1,v2,v3 as Integer

 v1 = 0 
 v2 = -1
 v3 = -2
      Child_sub v1, v2, v3
  msgbox "the variables are " & v1 & " ," & v2 & ", and " & v3
End Sub

Sub Child_sub(ByVal c1 as Integer, ByRef c2 as Integer, ByRef c3 as Integer)

c1 = 3
c2 = 4
c3 = 5

End Sub
```

I struggle to see why I get a compilation error (Compile error; ByRef Argument Type Mismatch; it appears at the Child_sub call, on the v2 argument). I use Excel 2016 for Home and Business. Any helpful tips?

Just to save from some potentially simple responses; I have not defined two subs with the same name (!), neither are the variables further redefined anywhere else in the code (checked). its quite a bizzare one for me. Please help, I'm an idiot!

Comment: A common VBA mistake: You have to specify the variable type for every variable, `Dim v1 as Integer, v2 as Integer, v3 as Integer`. In your code, only `v3` is of type `Integer`, `v1` and `v2` are `Variant`

Comment: instead of Dim v1,v2,v3 as Integer
try declaring variables one by one 
Dim v1  As Integer 
Dim v2  As Integer 
Dim v3  As Integer

Comment: Thank you guys, turns out I had to declare the variables as Integers one by one as FunThomas and Bijith T suggested. Is there no other way around this? In my code I have tens of variables, surely there must be a simpler way of declaring them? Well, at least now I have a solution that works and produces the desired outcome, so many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA doesn't have semicolons so you need to remove those. That is actually the only syntax error in your code. The others are just functionality.

`Dim v1,v2,v3 as Integer` only makes v3 an Integer. You need to repeat the data type for every variable.

Finally, if you want the child sub to edit the variable you need the `ByRef` keyword. You used it on c2 and c3 but not on c1

```
Sub Parent_sub()
Dim v1 As Integer,v2 As Integer,v3 as Integer

v1 = 0
v2 = -1
v3 = -2
  Child_sub v1, v2, v3
msgbox "the variables are " & v1 & " ," & v2 & ", and " & v3
End Sub

Sub Child_sub(ByRef c1 as Integer, ByRef c2 as Integer, ByRef c3 as 
Integer)

c1 = 3
c2 = 4
c3 = 5

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks. For future use; I had already edited my code and removed the commas after v1=0;  etc, before I saw the response above, in case anyone wonders.

Comment: just to say that `ByRef` is the default mode in VBA, so you could just write `Sub Child_sub(c1 as Integer, c2 as Integer, c3 as Integer)`